# how to ignore the annotations at runtime of the Ant File

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, tomcat, ant, cxf

I'm trying [to deploy my application through the generation of a **War** file](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) using an Ant File, in which I've wrote this code:

```
<project name="HelloWorldWS" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Web Services build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
  <property name="webcontent"  location="WebContent"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
    description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution" >

    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution war" >

    <!-- Create the war distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/war"/>

    <!-- Follow standard WAR structure -->
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/" src="${webcontent}/WEB-INF/" />
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/classes/" src="${build}" />

    <jar jarfile="${dist}/war/HelloWorld-${DSTAMP}.war" basedir="${dist}/war/build/"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
    description="clean up" >

    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

IDE: **Eclipse**. Local server: **Tomcat 7**. 
And i'm using **Hibernate**

When I run that nt File, I got thsi error:

> Buildfile: E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\build.xml init: compile:
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\build.xml:21: warning:
>   'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to
>   build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
>       [javac] Compiling 45 source files to E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\build
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\CompteDAO.java:5:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Query;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\CompteDAO.java:6:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\CompteDAO.java:7:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:4:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:5:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Column;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:6:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Entity;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:7:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.FetchType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:8:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Id;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:9:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:10:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:11:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:12:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:13:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Table;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:16:
>   error: package org.hibernate.annotations does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection;
>       [javac]                                 ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:17:
>   error: package org.hibernate.annotations does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption;
>       [javac]                                 ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:19:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Entity
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Entity
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:20:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Table(name="compte")
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Table
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\User.java:4: error:
>   package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Column;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\User.java:5: error:
>   package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Entity;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\User.java:6: error:
>   package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Id;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\User.java:7: error:
>   package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\User.java:8: error:
>   package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Table;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\User.java:11:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Entity
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Entity
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\User.java:12:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Table(name="utilisateur")
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Table
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:2:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:3:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Column;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:4:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Entity;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:5:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:6:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:7:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Id;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:8:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:9:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:10:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Table;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:13:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Entity
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Entity
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Solde.java:14:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Table(name="solde")
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Table
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:3:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:4:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Column;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:5:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Entity;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:6:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:7:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:8:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Id;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:9:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:10:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:11:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Table;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:14:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Entity
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Entity
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java:15:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Table(name="mouvement_compte")
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Table
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:7:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:8:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Column;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:9:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Entity;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:10:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:11:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:12:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Id;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:13:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:14:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:15:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:16:
>   error: package javax.persistence does not exist
>       [javac] import javax.persistence.Table;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:19:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Entity
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Entity
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Virement.java:20:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] @Table(name="virement")
>       [javac]  ^
>       [javac]   symbol: class Table
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\Mouvement_CompteDAO.java:5:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Query;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\Mouvement_CompteDAO.java:6:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\Mouvement_CompteDAO.java:7:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\SoldeDAO.java:5:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Query;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\SoldeDAO.java:6:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\SoldeDAO.java:7:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\UserDAO.java:5:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Query;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\UserDAO.java:6:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\UserDAO.java:7:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\VirementDAO.java:5:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Query;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\VirementDAO.java:6:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\dao\VirementDAO.java:7:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java:3:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java:4:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java:5:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java:6:
>   error: package org.hibernate.cfg does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
>       [javac]                         ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java:9:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
>       [javac]                        ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class SessionFactory
>       [javac]   location: class HibernateUtils
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
>       [javac]                 ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Session
>       [javac]   location: class HibernateUtils
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
>       [javac]                                             ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class HibernateException
>       [javac]   location: class HibernateUtils
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\Service.java:17:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\Service.java:18:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Query;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\Service.java:19:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\Service.java:20:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Transaction;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\services\Service.java:33:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   private static Session s                      = null;
>       [javac]                  ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Session
>       [javac]   location: class Service
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\tests\test.java:6:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Query;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\tests\test.java:7:
>   error: package org.hibernate does not exist
>       [javac] import org.hibernate.Session;
>       [javac]                     ^
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\tests\test.java:12:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   private static Session s = null;
>       [javac]                  ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Session
>       [javac]   location: class test
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @Id
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Id
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:24:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @Column(name="compte_rib")
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Column
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:27:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class ManyToOne
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:28:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class LazyCollection
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:29:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @JoinColumn(name="compte_utilisateurIdentifiant")
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class JoinColumn
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:32:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @Column(name="compte_libelle")
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Column
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:35:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="compte")
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class OneToMany
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:36:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class LazyCollection
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:39:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @Column(name="compte_dateCreation", nullable=false)
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Column
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:41:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @Column(name="compte_dateMaj", nullable=false)
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Column
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:43:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @Column(name="compte_typeDevise", nullable=false)
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Column
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:45:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @Column(name="compte_situationCompte", nullable=false)
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class Column
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:48:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @OneToMany(mappedBy="compte2")
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class OneToMany
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:49:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class LazyCollection
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\src\com\bh\jpa\Compte.java:53:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]   @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
>       [javac]    ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class ManyToMany
>       [javac]   location: class Compte
>       [javac] 100 errors
>
> BUILD FAILED E:\Bibliothèque
>   logicielle\workspace\projetServices\build.xml:21: Compile failed; see
>   the compiler error output for details.
>
> Total time: 2 seconds

Any help please?

Comment: You need to set a classpath to compile your sources with javac

Comment: @NicolasLalevée, how do I please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the classpath and lib directory path.

```
<javac destdir="build/classes" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="true" srcdir="src" includeantruntime="false">
  <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
</javac>

<path id="compile.classpath">
  <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
  <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: where do I set this please?

Comment: It's a java project, I don't have this path in **WebContent/WEB-INF/lib**

Comment: Give the lib folder path. WebContent/WEB-INF/lib its a default lib path for java web project.

Comment: it's only a java project not a web one

Comment: In Java project, you need to give the includes lib path like this <zipgroupfileset dir="${dist}/includes/lib" includes="*.jar" excludes=""/>

Answer (score 0):

Include the compile.classpath path, and modify the compile target like this

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
  <javac destdir="${build}" debug="true" srcdir="${src}" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
  </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: what kind of JAR files do I need to include ?