# what's wrong with this Ant file please?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ant, cxf

I can't find a solution to fix this, can you help me please ?

```
    <project name="HelloWorldWS" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Web Services build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
  <property name="webcontent"  location="WebContent"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" 
        description="compile the source ">
      <javac destdir="${build}" debug="true" srcdir="${src}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
      </javac>
    </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution" >

    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="war" depends="compile"
    description="generate the distribution war" >

    <!-- Create the war distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/war"/>

    <!-- Follow standard WAR structure -->
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/" src="${webcontent}/WEB-INF/" />
    <copydir dest="${dist}/war/build/WEB-INF/classes/" src="${build}" />

    <jar jarfile="${dist}/war/HelloWorld-${DSTAMP}.war" basedir="${dist}/war/build/"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
    description="clean up" >

    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

I got this message :

> Buildfile: E:\Bibliothèque
>   logicielle\workspace\projetServices\build.xml init: compile:
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\dao\CompteDAO.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\dao\GenericDAO.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\dao\Mouvement_CompteDAO.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\dao\SoldeDAO.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\dao\UserDAO.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\dao\VirementDAO.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\Avis.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\Compte.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\Mouvement_Compte.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\Solde.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\User.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\V1.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\V2.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\jpa\Virement.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\methods\FileMethods.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\HibernateUtils.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\Serveur.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\Service.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\ServicesInterface.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\Avis.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\Compte.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ConsulterAvis.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ConsulterAvisResponse.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ConsulterListeCpt.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ConsulterListeCptResponse.java modified in the
>   future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ConsulterSldChqCpt.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ConsulterSldChqCptResponse.java modified in the
>   future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\Exception.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\Exception_Exception.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ListerOperations.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ListerOperationsResponse.java modified in the
>   future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\MouvementCompte.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ObjectFactory.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\Service.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ServiceService.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\Solde.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\User.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ValidationRIBC.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\ValidationRIBCResponse.java modified in the
>   future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\VirementCompteACompte.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\VirementCompteACompteResponse.java modified in
>   the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\VirementDeMasse.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\VirementDeMasseResponse.java modified in the
>   future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\services\client\package-info.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: com\bh\tests\test.java modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: hibernate.cfg.xml modified in the future.
>       [javac] Warning: log4j.properties modified in the future.
>       [javac] Compiling 45 source files to E:\Bibliothèque logicielle\workspace\projetServices\build
>
> BUILD FAILED E:\Bibliothèque
>   logicielle\workspace\projetServices\build.xml:21: Reference
>   compile.classpath not found.
>
> Total time: 705 milliseconds

[image]

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your: `compile.classpath` (`<classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>`) is not defined anywhere in the build script.

You have to define the path of your libraries. Something like this:

```
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib"/>
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Comment: What kind of libraries do I need to define their path? It's a java project

Comment: All the jar files (dependencies) of your project. If there is non you don't need to define this: `<classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>` at all.

Comment: look at this post please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828802/how-to-ignore-the-annotations-at-runtime-of-the-ant-file/17833084?noredirect=1#17833084

Comment: I got that posted error when I retire that <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>

Comment: From the error you've posted I see that your application is some kind of web service and however you projects needs dependencies to compile classes. Your question has tag: hibernate, cxf so for e.g. hibernate and cxf does not comes along with JDK, so you need hibernate and cxf jars to be included in your classpath. And all other required dependencies.

Comment: I've included my Hibernate Jars as **User Libraries** at that project but I always got these errors

Comment: I've updated my post, in which I've added my Hibernte library.

Comment: But that is only eclipse I assume? You have also to specify those libraries in your ant scrip like in my answer under `compile.classpath` element.